# Install4j installer package does not work on Odroid mini computer

Tags: install4j, odroid

The error message is the following:

```
Syntax error: "elif" unexpected (expecting "then")
```

---

We changed the "elif" to "else if", to check if it is working this way, but at next try we got another error message:

```
Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "do")
```

---

The installer works well on a Linux based PC.
It does not work only on Odroid mini pc.

---

The Odroid linux features are the following:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
Linux odroid 3.10.104-184 #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Feb 20 06:38:17 UTC 2017 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

---

The installer package (it is only one .sh file) starts with the folliwing lines:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Uncomment the following line to override the JVM search sequence
# INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE=
# Uncomment the following line to add additional VM parameters
# INSTALL4J_ADD_VM_PARAMS=


INSTALL4J_JAVA_PREFIX=""
GREP_OPTIONS=""

read_db_entry() {
  if [ -n "$INSTALL4J_NO_DB" ]; then
    return 1
  fi
  if [ ! -f "$db_file" ]; then
    return 1
  fi
  if [ ! -x "$java_exc" ]; then
    return 1
  fi
  found=1
  exec 7< $db_file
  while read r_type r_dir r_ver_major r_ver_minor r_ver_micro r_ver_patch r_ver_vendor<&7; do
    if [ "$r_type" = "JRE_VERSION" ]; then
  if [ "$r_dir" = "$test_dir" ]; then
        ver_major=$r_ver_major
        ver_minor=$r_ver_minor
        ver_micro=$r_ver_micro
        ver_patch=$r_ver_patch
      fi
    elif [ "$r_type" = "JRE_INFO" ]; then
      if [ "$r_dir" = "$test_dir" ]; then
        is_openjdk=$r_ver_major
        if [ "W$r_ver_minor" = "W$modification_date" ]; then
          found=0
          break
        fi
      fi
    fi
  done
  exec 7<&-

  return $found
}

create_db_entry() {
  tested_jvm=true
  version_output=`"$bin_dir/java" $1 -version 2>&1`
  is_gcj=`expr "$version_output" : '.*gcj'`
  is_openjdk=`expr "$version_output" : '.*OpenJDK'`
  if [ "$is_gcj" = "0" ]; then
    java_version=`expr "$version_output" : '.*"\(.*\)".*'`
    ver_major=`expr "$java_version" : '\([0-9][0-9]*\).*'`
    ver_minor=`expr "$java_version" : '[0-9][0-9]*\.\([0-9][0-9]*\).*'`
    ver_micro=`expr "$java_version" : '[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.\([0-9][0-9]*\).*'`
    ver_patch=`expr "$java_version" : '[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*[\._]\([0-9][0-9]*\).*'`
  fi
  if [ "$ver_patch" = "" ]; then
    ver_patch=0
  fi
  if [ -n "$INSTALL4J_NO_DB" ]; then
    return
...
```

Comment: What shell is being used?

Comment: @IngoKegel Dash is used.

Comment: So it looks like Dash is not supported by install4j scripts. I've added this to our issue tracker.